# Resume ending margin unchangeable

Tags: margins, cv, resume

I'm using res.cls to make a resume and it looks awesome, except that it puts the last two lines on the next page leaving almost an inch and a half of lower margin, and I can't adjust the lower margin using geometry without losing my sections in the margin. How do you adjust the lower margin

```
% LaTeX resume using res.cls
\documentclass[margin,11pt]{res}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}%%%%
\usepackage{anysize}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.8in} % set width of text portion
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\marginsize{.75in}{.75in}{.5in}{.5in}
\begingroup
    \fontsize{14pt}{12pt}\selectfont
    \centerline{\bf John Doe}
\endgroup

\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width 7.1in height 1pt}\smallskip
    123 Main ST \hfill (321) 654-0987 \\
    jdoe@mail.com \hfill \ULurl{https://github.com/jdoe}

\begin{resume}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without any check done before, I would assume, that `geometry` package might help

Comment: To expand on Christian's comment, I would have thought that `\newgeometry{bottom=Xmm}`, for an appropriate value of `X` would fix the problem. Or perhaps you want to change `\footskip`. I can't test this against your MWE, however, because I don't have `res.cls` installed...

Comment: Please always post a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}
```

on the page of interest to add 2 extra lines. Alternatively, you could enlarge your text block height by adding

```
\setlength{\textheight}{\dimexpr\textheight+2\baselineskip}
```

to your preamble.